# Ruby on Rails on IIS7 not loading assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iis-7, fastcgi

Hit there,
I am trying to run RoR3 on IIS7 (Win 2k8 64bit) with the Help of the HeliconZoo Module. But sadly Ruby does not load any assets (images/javascripts/stylesheets) from the app/ folder.

Everything should be installed properly and "Static Content" is enabled in IIS. I can also access those files by entering the correct URL to it but they are not being used or shown in my dynamic views.

Is it rather an issue with my app or IIS? Do i have to set some special permissions to those assetts maybe?

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any help!

**Update: If i check the source from the rendered page the referring assets are linked from the root folder, so assetss are expected to be in "wwwroot/assets" instead of "wwwroot/mysite/public/assets" where they actually are being compiled to.**

**Obviously i cannot create a virtual folder for the assets since i want to run multiple apps on that site...**

Comment: What version of Rails are you using ?

Comment: RoR3 - 1.9.3 Ruby and 3.1 Rails

Comment: If you are running your app in the production environment, assets should be present in the public/assets directory. Is it correct ? Does IIS reference this directory for static content ?

Comment: Did you precompile your assets?  (`rake assets:precompile')

Comment: I have all assets in the folder /app/assets/ aswell as in /public/ and that should normaly do it (at least one of the sources :/ ). What do you mean with the IIS reference as static content? Is it some setting?

Comment: Yes Wizard of Ogz i tried already to precompile but it seems not to have any impact

Comment: By reference I meant that IIS should serve static content from /public/assets (Rails will search your assets search for your assets using the URL `http://yourapp/assets`).

Comment: Did you try to create an "/assets" virtual directory under IIS and make it map the physical /public/assets directory ?

Comment: /public/assets is the directory "rake assets:precompile" should create and store all compiled assets in there right? But this is not happening. Maybe some issue with the Rails version?

Comment: So the physical path /public/assets does not exist for me. However HeliconZoo is automatically creating 3 folders in /public "images, stylesheets, javascripts" isn't that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Seems like it was an issue with the Rails version. I fixed the precompile thing. So now "rake assets:precompile" correctly precompiles the assets and puts them in public/assets folder. But the source of the page shows that the server is expecting the assets folder to be in root, so in wwwroot/assets instead of wwwroot/myapp/public/assets where they actually are. So the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

In the [Helicon Zoo usage page for RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019071/ruby-on-rails-on-iis7-not-loading-assets) there is a web.config example with special rules for MS URL Rewrite which are used to load assets with correct location.